# How to use the mongodb localhost exception?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, localhost, authorization

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#localhost-exception):

> The localhost exception allows you to **enable access control and then**
>   **create the first user in the system**. With the localhost exception,
>   after you enable access control, connect to the localhost interface
>   and **create the first user in the admin database**. The first user must
>   have privileges to create other users, such as a user with the
>   **userAdmin** or **userAdminAnyDatabase** role.

So I run the latest mongo with enabled access control (--auth):

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 mongo --auth
```

connect with my shell and try to create the **admin** user:

```
mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.2
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser(
...   {
...     user: "admin",
...     pwd: "password",
...     roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
...   }
... )
2018-10-03T15:29:30.234+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't add user: command createUser requires authentication :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1491:15
@(shell):1:1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not connecting to localhost but to the exported port. 
For the exception to work you need to connect to localhost from within the container.
E.g.:

```
docker exec -it `docker ps --filter ancestor=mongo --format "{{.ID}}"` mongo
```